# Shower Head Taking a Long Time Operate

Tags: plumbing, water, shower

I do not know about plumbing at all, to be honest.

My question is - I was wondering if anyone knows why I need to stand for 1-2 minutes turning the shower head diverter knob back and forth until finally the water comes through the shower head and not the faucet?

I did have some luck with putting the hot and cold water handles about equal to each other, and that gave me water from the shower head within 10 seconds. My habit though is to have more hot water by turning the hot knob further than the cold to get the water toasty, but that's when it causes me to need to stand there for a prolonged time until the water comes out from the head.

Thanks, sorry for the long question[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T2nm.jpg)

Comment: you are not supposed to move the diverter back and forth ..... all you have do, is to turn on the two taps so that the temperature of the water, that comes out of the tap, is acceptable, then flip the diverter lever

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you are saying, but that is what I am doing. I adjust the two taps to my liking, then I flip the diverter, but the water doesn't come out of the head until 1-2 minutes later, only continuing out of the faucet until then.

Comment: Could the diverter handle be slipping? You should feel the mechanism moving inside when you turn the handle.

Comment: So, if you move the diverter, and then let go, a minute or two later it will start coming out of the shower?

Comment: I do feel something inside when I turn the diverter, I can take it off and see what it looks like inside, make sure everything looks okay.

Yes, if I move it and let go, it's another minute or two before the water comes out of the shower head.